# How to setup an internal loadbalancer in a EU GKE region to be used from US GKE over network peering

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

In our EU region we have an operations cluster, where we serve all of our managements services. 
Next to it we have an EU cluster in the same region, where we service all of our regional services.
We also have a US cluster where the regional services are running for the US.

I have setup internal loadbalancers, so I can access some of the management services from the regional EU services.

But for some reason I cannot access those management services, in the EU operations cluster, from our US regional cluster.

The EU regional services and EU operations cluster are both in the same VPC. The US regional services are in a different VPC.
To get this to work, I've added VPC network peerings between both VPC, but still no way to access a simple apache server in the EU operations cluster.

Comment: What's the status of your Peering? Did you do it both ways? Are the ranges of the VPCs' subnets **not** overlapped?

Comment: Peering is up, all the ways (we have 4 VPC's that are connected all ways)

Answer (score 0):

Internal load balancers in GCP are regional resources so traffic from the EU site won't be able to use the Load Balancer in the US region.

One way around this is to use a proxy in the US region.